# Express 4.18 body parsing

Tags: node.js, express

im currently using express 4.18.3 and woundering why my req body wont get parsed?

```js
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express'

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import v1 from './routes/index'

dotenv.config()
const app: Express = express()

app.use('/', v1)
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const startExpressServer = () => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
}

startExpressServer()
```

Req.body is currently undefined.
My request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/user/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "apiKey": "test"
}'
```

Comment: Order of middlewares matters.

Comment: That should be the reason, tyvm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work

File tree

[image]

`main.js`

```js
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import routes from './routes/index.js';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use('/', routes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const startExpressServer = () => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
};

startExpressServer();
```

`./routes/index.js`

```js
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/user/login', (req, res) => {
  const { apiKey } = req.body;
  res.send('Login successful');
});

export default router;
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.18.3"
  }
}
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express dotenv
```

##### Run server

```
node main.js
```

##### Call it

```
curl --silent --location 'http://localhost:3000/user/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "apiKey": "test"
}'
```

Call by curl

[image]

Call by Postman

[image]